# Django - How to deny the user to vote in his own objects?

Tags: django, django-voting

I'm new to Django and having some doubts on how to do this. I've installed an APP called Django-voting, https://github.com/jezdez/django-voting/

This APP allow the user to vote on is own objects. I need to deny this but not sure on how to do it. How can I know the owner of an object?

The code that I've to override is this view:

```
def vote_on_object(request, model, direction, post_vote_redirect=None,
    object_id=None, slug=None, slug_field=None, template_name=None,
    template_loader=loader, extra_context=None, context_processors=None,
    template_object_name='object', allow_xmlhttprequest=False):
    """
    Generic object vote function.

    The given template will be used to confirm the vote if this view is
    fetched using GET; vote registration will only be performed if this
    view is POSTed.

    If ``allow_xmlhttprequest`` is ``True`` and an XMLHttpRequest is
    detected by examining the ``HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`` header, the
    ``xmlhttp_vote_on_object`` view will be used to process the
    request - this makes it trivial to implement voting via
    XMLHttpRequest with a fallback for users who don't have JavaScript
    enabled.

    Templates:``<app_label>/<model_name>_confirm_vote.html``
    Context:
    object
        The object being voted on.
    direction
        The type of vote which will be registered for the object.
    """
    if allow_xmlhttprequest and request.is_ajax():
    return xmlhttprequest_vote_on_object(request, model, direction,
                                         object_id=object_id, slug=slug,
                                         slug_field=slug_field)

    if extra_context is None:
    extra_context = {}
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    return redirect_to_login(request.path)

    try:
    vote = dict(VOTE_DIRECTIONS)[direction]
    except KeyError:
    raise AttributeError("'%s' is not a valid vote type." % direction)

    # Look up the object to be voted on
    lookup_kwargs = {}
    if object_id:
    lookup_kwargs['%s__exact' % model._meta.pk.name] = object_id
    elif slug and slug_field:
    lookup_kwargs['%s__exact' % slug_field] = slug
    else:
    raise AttributeError('Generic vote view must be called with either '
                         'object_id or slug and slug_field.')
    try:
    obj = model._default_manager.get(**lookup_kwargs)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    raise Http404('No %s found for %s.' %
                  (model._meta.app_label, lookup_kwargs))

    if request.method == 'POST':
    if post_vote_redirect is not None:
        next = post_vote_redirect
    elif 'next' in request.REQUEST:
        next = request.REQUEST['next']
    elif hasattr(obj, 'get_absolute_url'):
        if callable(getattr(obj, 'get_absolute_url')):
            next = obj.get_absolute_url()
        else:
            next = obj.get_absolute_url
    else:
        raise AttributeError('Generic vote view must be called with either '
                             'post_vote_redirect, a "next" parameter in '
                             'the request, or the object being voted on '
                             'must define a get_absolute_url method or '
                             'property.')
    Vote.objects.record_vote(obj, request.user, vote)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
    else:
    if not template_name:
        template_name = '%s/%s_confirm_vote.html' % (
            model._meta.app_label, model._meta.object_name.lower())
    t = template_loader.get_template(template_name)
    c = RequestContext(request, {
        template_object_name: obj,
        'direction': direction,
    }, context_processors)
    for key, value in extra_context.items():
        if callable(value):
            c[key] = value()
        else:
            c[key] = value
    response = HttpResponse(t.render(c))
    return response
```

I think I've to add some kind of verification here,

```
Vote.objects.record_vote(obj, request.user, vote)
```

Any clues on this subject?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This app doesn't manage whether a `user` is owner or not of any `object` where he can make a vote, so you need to keep this control in each model who represents an entity able to be voted. For example, if you have a model `A` and you wish to know which user is owner of `A` you should have a `user` relation with the model `A` for tracking model owner users. We can represent this through an example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import messages

class A(models.Model):
    owner_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

so in any place on your code (in a view or in a verification method) you can do something like this:

```
# I will call `user_who_votes`  the user who is making the action of voting
# if you are in a view or have a `request` instance, you can access to its instance,
# as surely you already know, with `user_who_votes = request.user`, always checking  
# this user is authenticated (`if request.user.is_authenticated():`).
try:
    # Checking if the user who is voting is `A`'s owner,
    # if he is, so you can register a message and show it
    # to the user when you estimate (it is only an idea,
    # maybe you can have a better option, of course). 
    a = A.objects.get(owner_user=user_who_votes)
    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'You can not vote on your own entities.'))
except A.DoesNotexist:
    # In this point you are sure at all that `user_who_votes`
    # isn't the owner of `A`, so this user can vote.
    Vote.objects.record_vote(a, user_who_votes, vote)
```

Hope this can help you.